# Arrays.sort() vs. Sorting Algorithms

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Just a general question. I've seen Arrays.sort() been mentioned for sorting arrays with the term "cheating" often coming up afterwards. Why is Arrays.sort() considered cheating and is it more or less efficient than using some kind of sorting algorithm?

Comment: `Arrays.sort()` uses `Dual-Pivot Quicksort` algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most language-provided implementations of sort are *really good*. I doubt for most cases -- unless your have extra knowledge about the type of data that might help you sort -- that you will ever be able to beat it.

However, using them doesn't provide you with the 'knowledge' about how they work. If your goal is to get stuff done, or provide production-ready code, use the pre-built methods. If you goal is to gain knowledge or demonstrate knowledge, write your own.

If you are asked to sort something at an interview or an assignment, be very clear with the interviewer/teacher: "Do you want me to implement sorting myself, or use a pre-built sorting function?" If you don't ask, you could be docked either way. Some interviewers or teachers might think "oh, she doesn't know how to implement her own sort" and others might think "why isn't she using the sort that is part of the language?"

Answer (score 3):

"Cheating" ? Only if your homework want you to Sort a collection and you use `Arrays.sort` while your teacher meant you to implement your own.

Other than that, `Arrays.sort` is in general the best way to sort your collection.

Answer (score 2):

The efficiency of a sort() method depends on the efficiency of the implemented algorithm. According to Java documentation

> The sorting algorithm is a Dual-Pivot Quicksort by Vladimir Yaroslavskiy, Jon Bentley, and Joshua Bloch. This algorithm offers O(n log(n)) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance, and is typically faster than traditional (one-pivot) Quicksort implementations

which is a quick and stable algorithm.

I presume that the cheating part is that in an exercise someone might prefer to use the Array.sort() method instead of developing a sorting algorithm, which is really bad... So lets put no blame on Array.sort()  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit vague, however maybe what you want to know is how do sorting algorithms compare. @Ashot mentioned that `Arrays.sort` uses a Dual-Pivot Quicksort algorithm. Quicksort is just like it's name, it's quick.

But take a look at this Wikipedia article that compares sorting algorithms:
[Sorting algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

If you are serious about improving performance, then you need to get more familiar with the different sorting algorithms and why each one of them *might* be used. Depending on your application you may choose a certain algorithm - there is no one good algorithm.

Comment: Yes I was wondering whether or not it had performance benefits over manual coding other algorithms or is it just the fact that it is less fuss and less work to code

Comment: Hi @Schonge. Actually, you might want to code your own algorithm if you *really* need to get performance improvements. I did previous program my own Merge Sort (and others - I forget) algorithms; the only thing is, you have to read up on the algorithms and understand why they might be used. A good algorithms book would also be helpful.

Comment: I did a module in university on data-structures and algorithms about 2 years ago. In my final year now so I'm brushing up on them again before going for job interviews in the summer. It was interesting to see what people thought about Arrays.sort(). I always thought it was frowned upon to use. Obviously it shouldn't be used when learning but it's good to have those options available. I personally like coding my own stuff anyway even if it is reinventing the wheel, I get more satisfaction from it.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not cheating. Maybe someone is looking for you to show you know how to do a sort as part of a test or interview, but take advantage of the JDK methods that are there. The algorithm used (last time I checked) is a [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort). If there is a sorting algorithm that is more optimal for your case, then use that one. Otherwise, don't rewrite what you don't need to.

Comment: The Javadoc states that it's a tuned quicksort.

Comment: The specifics probably vary across different versions of the JDK - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(Object[])

Answer (score 1):

Because if your teacher told you to sort and array and you sorted it this way, this is not what he wanted you to do. He probably wanted you to implement say heap sort or quick sort on your own. In real world though, it is not cheating at all to use this method for sorting an array.

Answer (score 1):

I would only been considered cheating in an interview or homework context, where the assignment would be to write a sorting algorithms and you would use Arrays.sort()  instead.